# Counting features in Geodatabase using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, esri-geodatabase, arccatalog, count

I try to find out the numbers of feature in a geodatabase. I can't find any tool or option in ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2 or ArcCatalog.

Comment: You mean, like [GetCount](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm)?

Comment: "The number of feature in a geodatabase"?  Do you mean number of features in a feature class or are you looking for the total count of all features in all feature classes in a geodatabase?

Comment: I mean the  total count of all features  in all feature classes in a geodatabase.

Comment: In other words, I want to know the total number of Shapefiles in a geodatabase.

Comment: There are zero shapefiles in a geodatabase (completely different formats). The number of **tables** in a file or enterprise geodatabase can be calculated by listing them.

Comment: To add up the counts of features in all feature classes within a geodatabase I would use ArcPy to list the feature classes then iterate that list to run GetCount on each one and sum the total while doing it. I think you should make a code attempt and focus your question on one of ArcGIS Pro or ArcCatalog.